# How do I add alpha beta pruning to a minimax tic tac toe game?

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm making an unbeatable tic tac toe program using the minimax algorithm. The program control has to traverse through a LOT (over 200k) of nodes in the tree to choose a position (obviously it decreases with every move). But, I want to make the program faster using alpha beta pruning specifically. I checked out some of the ways to do it on the internet but it seems to me like my code is not compatible with those methods.

Any ideas on how to get this done will be really useful for me.  This program is for an assignment I need to submit tonight, so it would be super nice if anyone could help me out with this.

The code I've written for the program is below (it is in Python 3.6)

Thanks in advance!

```
import sys
move = -1
n = 0
nodes = 0
def evaluateBoard(board):
    global n
    #Checking for rows
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(n):
        res = 0
        for j in range(n):
           res += board[cnt * n + j] 
        cnt += 1
        if res == n:
            return 1
        elif res == -n:
            return -1

    #Checking for columns
    for i in range(n):
        res = 0
        for j in range(n):
            res += board[i + n * j]
        if res == n:
            return 1
        elif res == -n:
            return -1

    #Checking for diagonals
    res = res2 = 0
    for i in range(n):
        res += board[i * (n + 1)]   
        res2 += board[(i + 1) * (n - 1)]
    if n in [res, res2]:
        return 1
    elif -n in [res, res2]:
        return -1

    return 0

def checkNonTerminal(board):
   for pos in board:
       if pos == 0:
           return 1
   return 0

def getScore(board, depth):
    if evaluateBoard(board) == 1:
        return 10 - depth
    elif evaluateBoard(board) == -1:
        return depth - 10
    else:
        return 0

def minimax(board, turn, depth, alpha, beta):
    global nodes
    if evaluateBoard(board) == 0 and checkNonTerminal(board) == 0:
        return getScore(board, depth)
    global move
    moves = list()
    scores = list()

    for square, pos in enumerate(board):
        if pos == 0:
            nodes += 1
            #print(board)
            new_board = board.copy()
            new_board[square] = turn
            moves.append(square)
            #print("Moves:", moves, "depth:", depth, "turn:", turn, checkNonTerminal(new_board) == 0)
            if evaluateBoard(new_board) in [1, -1] or checkNonTerminal(new_board) == 0:
                move = square
                return getScore(new_board, depth)
            scores.append(minimax(new_board, turn * -1, depth + 1, alpha, beta))
#    print("moves",moves)
#    print("scores", scores) 

    if turn == 1:
        move = moves[scores.index(max(scores))]
        return max(scores)
    elif turn == -1:
        move = moves[scores.index(min(scores))]
        return min(scores)

def displayBoard(board):
    global n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if board[n*i+j] == 1:
                print("x",end=" ")
            elif board[n*i+j] == -1:
                print("o", end=" ")
            else:
                print(".", end = " ")
        print()
    print()

def main():      
    global n 
    global move
    n = 3
    first_turn = input("Would you like to go first (Y/N)?: ")
    if first_turn in ['Y', 'y']:
        first_turn = -1
        cnt = 1
    else:
        first_turn = 1
        cnt = 2
    board = [0] * 9
    displayBoard(board)
    while evaluateBoard(board) == 0 and checkNonTerminal(board) == 1:

        if cnt % 2 == 0:
            minimax(board, 1, 0)
            #print(score)
            board[move] = 1
            displayBoard(board)
        else:
            choice = eval(input("Enter your choice (1-9): "))
            if board[choice - 1] != 0:
                print("No cheating!")
                sys.exit([0])
            else:
                board[choice - 1] = -1
                displayBoard(board)
        cnt += 1

    if evaluateBoard(board) == 1:
        print("You lose!")
    elif evaluateBoard(board) == -1:
        print("You win!")
    else:
        print("It's a draw!")

    print(nodes,"nodes")

main()
```

Comment: It might make more sense to take a heuristic approach until the input size becomes more manageable, say 5! rather then 9!. I would think it highly inefficient to scour over 360,000 possibilities when you could effectively achieve the same result by choosing what is known to be an optimal move at the start, and then using mini-max from there.

Comment: Use this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning#Pseudocode) to get an idea of the alpha beta algorithm. Your function call looks similar. This is the best pseudocode I could find which even helped me.